# looking for help for this entry "TP" in Diedendorf church records

Tags: translation

What does TP stand for in Diedendorf early church records.

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Could you provide a link to the church records so we can maybe deduce the meaning from context?

Comment: An image of the page in question might be very good.

Comment: This question would be better asked on http://genealogy.stackexchange.com. @Mods: I'd suggest migrating the question.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is, that it abbreviates *Taufpate* (godfather).